# Can I remove the indentation in {reftex-toc}?

Tags: indentation, auctex, reftex-mode

I am new user of auctex/reftex and the `reftex-toc`-function is brilliant. 
However, on my small screen a lot of space is wasted when I have a document with only chapters, or even sections. (I put the toc on the left side of my 11-inch screen.)

Parts are indented with one leading space, chapters with three, sections with five. 
Is it possible to remove/hide the extraneous indentation when it is not needed?

Examples:

```
TABLE-OF-CONTENTS on ~/test.tex
SPC=view TAB=goto RET=goto+hide [q]uit [r]escan [l]abels [f]ollow [x]r [?]Help
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Part I Part level
    1 Chapter level
      1.1 Section Level
```

Document with no parts or chapters:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      1 This document has only sections
      2 Like this
      3 And this
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indentation is set by variable `reftex-level-indent`. Its default value is 2, that is why indentation is 1,3,5 etc.

> -- User Option: reftex-level-indent
>
> ```
> Number of spaces to be used for indentation per section level.
> ```

You may simply set it to 0.

This way, all levels are indented at 1, I don't know how to get rid of the remaining initial space.

Comment: Great! But this removes the subsequent indentation? Well. I guess setting it to 1 is a good compromise. Would be nice to get rid of the initial space though.